# Overload resolution and async await

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-4.5, c#-5.0

Below code gives error CS0121,

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: '`RunTask(System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>)`' and '`RunTask(System.Action)`'

```
static void RunTask(Func<Task> intTask)
{
}

static void RunTask(Action voidTask)
{
}

static async Task DoAsyncTask()
{
    await Task.Delay(500);
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var asyncTask = new Func<Task>(DoAsyncTask);
    RunTask(DoAsyncTask);
}
```

But below code can compile

```
static void RunTask(Func<Task> intTask)
{
}

static void RunTask(Action voidTask)
{
}

static async Task DoAsyncTask()
{
    await Task.Delay(500);
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var asyncTask = new Func<Task>(DoAsyncTask);
    RunTask(asyncTask);
}
```

Why so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C# compiler does not take return type of a delegate into account when trying to decide the best overloaded method that takes a delegate.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225125/why-doesnt-cs-overload-resolution-work-between-funct-t-and-actiont)

Comment: Fair enough, but why a delegate can compile?

Comment: Because you've explicitly declared the type of asyncTask to be Func<Task>, which makes it easy for the compiler.