# Ambiguous C# method call with delegates

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, delegates, ambiguous

In my application, I have code similar to following:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Method(uri => Task.FromResult(uri));
        }

        static void Method(Func<Uri, Uri> transformer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        static void Method(Func<Uri, Task<Uri>> transformer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

As expected, running this code calls the second overload of 'Method', the one expecting a function delegate that returns a task. However, if i change the code to avoid using the anonymous method in Main:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Method(Method2);
        }

        static Task<Uri> Method2(Uri uri)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(uri);
        }

        static void Method(Func<Uri, Uri> transformer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        static void Method(Func<Uri, Task<Uri>> transformer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

The C# compiler now complains that my call to 'Method' is ambiguous. What am i missing?

Comment: you are not passing a Uri to Method2.

Comment: @SamAxe he doesn't mean to. He's trying to convert a *method group* (`Method2`) to a delegate (`Func<Uri, Task<Uri>>`)

Comment: Possibly because `TResult` in `Func<in T, out TResult>` is covariant.

Comment: as resharper suggests. cast `Method((Func<Uri, Task<Uri>>) Method2);`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, ReSharper suggest that to resolve the ambiguity. The question is why is there ambiguity at all as clearly there's no implicit conversion from `Func<Uri, Uri>` to `Method2`.

Comment: @haim770 its because of return type `Task<Uri>`. seems compiler does not even look in to it to resolve this ambiguity._ or maybe Task<Uri> it self returns Uri?

Comment: @richzilla This is a dupe indeed, and the answer is here: "The principle here is that determining method group convertibility requires selecting a method from a method group using overload resolution, and **overload resolution does not consider return types**."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long answer is at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2058854/1223597 (as richzilla pointed out).

The short answer is that the C# compiler team chose to make method group conversions (like `Method(Method2)`) ignore the return type (here of `Method2`). This gives them flexibility in how `Expression` trees are parsed. Unfortunately that means the compiler cannot implicitly choose between your 2 `Method` signatures.

When doing a lambda conversion, (`Method(uri => Task.FromResult(uri))`), the compiler team doesn't need to worry about expression tree parsing, so they **do** consider return types.