# Distinguish between void and task returning method

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm working on a class which has a method with `Action<T>` parameter:

```
public void RegisterCallback<T> (Action<T> callback);
```

This works good enough.

```
instance.RegisterCallback<string>(Callback); //method group
instance.RegisterCallback<string>(t => {}); //lambda
```

Now I want to create an overload for this method which accepts `async` method. So that I can use it with task returning callbacks and treat them in a different way.

```
instance.RegisterCallback<string>(AsyncCallback); //method group with async
```

Where `AsyncCallback` is

```
    private Task AsyncCallback(string s)
    {
        return Task.Delay(0);
    }
```

The naive approach was to have a method like this one:

```
void RegisterCallback<T>(Func<T, Type> callback);
```

It has some problems though:

```
//1
instance.RegisterCallback<string>(async t => await Task.Delay(0));
//2
instance.RegisterCallback<string>(AsyncCallback); //method group with async
```

the first one gets resolved to `Action<T> callback` overload and the second fails to compile because of ambiguous invocation.

Well, that [makes sense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057146/compiler-ambiguous-invocation-error-anonymous-method-and-method-group-with-fun) and I'm ok about this interface:

```
 void RegisterAsyncCallback<T>(Func<T, Task> callback);
```

However these two calls are compiled with no problems:

```
   instance.RegisterCallback<string>(async t => await Task.Delay(0));
   instance.RegisterAsyncCallback<string>(async t => await Task.Delay(0));
```

Is there a way to design this public api so that a user will only use `void` callbacks with one method and task returning with another.

Perhaps someone can point me to the existing api where similar problem was solved?

The full code can be found [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vU1Rd8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no good solution here; you'll either have the ambiguous call error with method overloads, or you'll have a whole new API.

Personally, I would add the `Func<T, Task>` overload and take the breaking change, no longer allowing method overloads. Alternatively, you can create both overloads on the new method (`RegisterCallbackEx`?) and mark the old one as `Obsolete` - this would allow older code to compile but encourage devs to change the calls.

> Perhaps someone can point me to the existing api where similar problem was solved?

Well, I can give you an example where a similar problem *wasn't* solved. :)

`Task.Factory.StartNew` is commonly used to queue work to the thread pool. It's `Action`-based, and I believe it works with method groups.

When the .NET team wanted to add async support, they introduced a new API instead: `Task.Run`, which is overloaded for `Action` and `Func<Task>`.

(Note that in this case, `Task.Run` technically supports only a subset of `StartNew` uses, and `StartNew` was not marked `Obsolete`).

They considered their options, but this was the best they could come up with. Note that the following problems still exist, and developers ask questions about both of these points rather regularly here on SO:

- `Task.Run` does not support method groups.
- `StartNew` will compile just fine with `async` lambdas, but will behave in surprising ways (due to `async void`).

Since they were changing the .NET BCL, backwards compatibility was paramount. For a personal library, I prefer safer/cleaner APIs over strict backwards compatibility, so I would make the other choice in your situation (i.e., just add a `Func<T, Task>` overload as part of a major version upgrade).

Comment: Thanks for the good example with Task.Run. I was looking for something like that.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to design this public api so that a user will only use void callbacks with one method and task returning with another.

No, not really. The issue is the `Action<T>` delegate. It allows for a large number of various lambda expressions as you have already discovered. The one major issue that you will run into with the `RegisterCallback(Action<T> callback)` - if anyone uses it like this:

```
instance.RegisterCallback<string>(async _ => await Task.Delay(0));
```

They are creating an `async void` and this is a huge problem. You had the right idea with the `Func<T, Task>`. Also, I like your idea to rename the function and adding "Async" seems appropriate, `RegisterAsyncCallback(Func<string, Task> callback)`.

Comment: This is spot on - I forgot `async void` can be cast to `Action<T>`. As far as I'm aware, there's no way to write a method which explicitly forbids async/non-async delegate parameters

Comment: I'm not sure what do want to know about implementation? It's just a callback(value). I need a bit more complicated error handling in the async overload.

Comment: Update your fiddle with more code and I'll have another look.  The issue that I see is `Action<T>` will always accept `RegisterCallback<string>(async _ => await Task.Delay(0));`. So there is no way to distinguish.

Comment: That makes more sense now, originally you didn't provide that `IMyInterface` was actually `IMyInterface<T>`.  Like I said (and Steve Cleary agrees), add the `Func<T, Task>` and make the best of it.